# Dynamic domain that gets list of saved asset queries as values?

Tags: maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1:

I have a custom field in PMs called SAVEDASSETQUERY.

I would like to add a domain to this field that is a list of all saved asset queries that the user has access to.

- It would be ideal if the domain were dynamic. If a new saved asset query were added to Maximo, then it would automatically show up in the domain/field in the PM application.

The reason for doing this is: I want to avoid data entry errors in the SAVEDASSETQUERY field.

Is it possible to do this with automation scripting, or would it require Java customization?

Comment: Are you reinventing the wheel since View/Manager Queries already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a standard TABLE domain on the QUERY table object to achieve this. To filter on the user's queries (attribute OWNER), you would use the `:&USERNAME&` special bind variable.

Table domains:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/adding-lookup-functionality-field-maximo-using-table-domain

Bind variables:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/username-appname-and-other-special-bind-variables-you-can-use